# Re-orderable listview doesn't call removeRows()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview, qabstractlistmodel

I'm trying to implement a listview that is capable to perform internal moves (MoveAction) as well as accepts drops from outside (CopyAction).

I've read on some sites that Qt will call removeRows() if we dropMimeData() returns with True to a QtCore.Qt.MoveAction.
However, with my code outlined below "removeRows() called" is never printed.

I cannot call it in dropMimeData() myself, because I have no knowledge on which index should be removed. (And I think you are not supposed to do it yourself)

Moreover, I see the problem that it matters if the it is moved to an entry before its original index or after.
(before = we now need to delete old index plus 1)

```
class ToolListModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, tabText):
        super(ToolListModel, self).__init__()
        self.tabText = tabText

        #integrity check
        jsonConfigHelper.validateBookmark_data()
        self.modelData = jsonConfigHelper.getBookmark_data().get(self.tabText)

    def writeTabToJSON(self):
        data = jsonConfigHelper.getBookmark_data()
        data[self.tabText] = self.modelData
        jsonConfigHelper.overrideBookmark_data(data)


    # Returns the list of allowed MIME types
    def mimeTypes(self):
        return [ "application/x-commander"]


    # Returns an object that contains serialized items of data corresponding to the list of indexes specified. 
    # The format used to describe the encoded data is obtained from the mimeTypes() function
    def mimeData(self, indices):
        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        #data to bytes

        encodedData = QtCore.QByteArray(indices[0].data(99).get(TOKENS.FUNCTION_LABEL).encode('utf-8'))

        mimeData.setData("application/x-commander", encodedData)
        print(mimeData)
        return mimeData

    def dropMimeData(self, mimeData, action, row, column, parent):
        if self.canDropMimeData(mimeData, action, row, column, parent) == False:
            return False
        else:
            encodedData = mimeData.data("application/x-commander")
            decodedData = encodedData.data().decode()

            #look for precofigured shortname if none found leave empty
            shortname = globalVars.DATA.get(decodedData).get(TOKENS.FUNCTION_SHORTNAME, "none")

            tempDict = {
                TOKENS.FUNCTION_LABEL : decodedData, 
                TOKENS.FUNCTION_SHORTNAME : shortname
            }

            if action == QtCore.Qt.CopyAction:
                print ("Copying")
                # inserting 'count' empty rows starting at 'row'
                self.insertRows(row, 1, QtCore.QModelIndex())
                idx = self.index(row, 0, QtCore.QModelIndex())
                self.setData(idx, tempDict)
                return True

            if action == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction:
                print ("Moving")
                self.insertRows(row, 1, QtCore.QModelIndex())
                idx = self.index(row, 0, QtCore.QModelIndex())
                self.setData(idx, tempDict)
                # remove calling
                return True

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):

        print("setData() called")
        self.modelData[index.row()] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        self.writeTabToJSON()
        return True


    def insertRows(self, row, count, parent):

        print("insertRows() called")
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1)
        for i in range(0, count):
            print(i)
            self.modelData.insert(row + i, dict())
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

    def removeRows(self, row, count, parent):

        print("removeRows() called")
        self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row + count - 1)
        for i in range(count, 0, -1):
            print(i)
            self.modelData.pop(row - i + 1)
        self.endRemoveRows()
        self.writeTabToJSON()
        return True

    def canDropMimeData(self, mimeData, action, row, column, parent):
        if mimeData.hasFormat("application/x-commander") != True:
            return False
        if action != QtCore.Qt.MoveAction and action != QtCore.Qt.CopyAction :
            return False
        if column > 0: 
            return False

        return True

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction        

    # moves count rows starting with the given sourceRow under parent sourceParent to row destinationChild under parent destinationParent.
    def moveRows(self, sourceParent, sourceRow, count, destinationParent, destinationChild):
        self.beginMoveRows(sourceParent, sourceRow, sourceRow + count -1, destinationParent, destinationChild)
        self.modelData.insert(destinationChild, self.modelData.pop(sourceRow))
        self.endMoveRows()

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable
```

Here is the method from my custom ListView that creates the Drag

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if event.buttons() != QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
        return
    if (event.pos() - self.dragRelPos).manhattanLength() < QtWidgets.QApplication.startDragDistance():
        return

    vpos = self.viewport().mapFromGlobal(self.dragGlobPos)
    index = self.indexAt(vpos)
    row = index.row()
    col = index.column()

    if not index.isValid(): # don't acc
        return
    else:
        dragObj = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        mimeData = self.model().mimeData([index])
        dragObj.setMimeData(mimeData)
        dragObj.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
```